# EncodingTranslatorStream - A stream object that translates character encoding

Tags: c#, stream

This class is a stream designed to perform character encoding translation.  So you instantiate it, pass an input stream, and specify the input encoding and desired output encoding, so that when you read from this stream, is will translate the source data from one encoding type to another.

I'm interested in a general code review on style/organization of code as well as for any apparent bugs and performance considerations

```
/// <summary>
/// This class is a stream designed to perform character encoding translation from one encoding to another.
/// </summary>
public class EncodingTranslatorStream : System.IO.Stream
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Input data.  This is the data that well be decoded, and re-encoded in the specified encoding
    /// </summary>
    private System.IO.Stream strInput_m;

    /// <summary>
    /// Input stream reader.  This will be responsible for decoding the input bytes into unicode characters based on the specified input encoding
    /// </summary>
    private StreamReader srInput_m;

    /// <summary>
    /// Output stream reader.  This will be responsible for encoding unicode characters into bytes based on the specified output encoding
    /// </summary>
    private StreamWriter swOutput_m;

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds a stream of bytes, and when read, the bytes are automatically removed from the stream
    /// </summary>
    private Stream strOut_m;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.  Specifies the input and output encoding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strInput">Input data, that will be decoded and re-encode into the specified output encoding</param>
    /// <param name="encodingIn">The input character encoding to use.</param>
    /// <param name="encodingOut">Output encoding</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The character encoding is set by the encoding parameter. 
    /// The StreamReader object attempts to detect the encoding by looking at the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise, the user-provided encoding is used. 
    /// </remarks>
    public EncodingTranslatorStream(System.IO.Stream strInput, Encoding encodingIn, Encoding encodingOut)
    {
        this.Init(strInput, encodingOut);
        this.srInput_m = new StreamReader(strInput, encodingIn);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.  Specifies the input and output encoding, and a byte order mark detection option for the input stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strInput">Input data, that will be decoded and re-encode into the specified output encoding</param>
    /// <param name="encodingIn">The input character encoding to use.</param>
    /// <param name="encodingOut">Output encoding</param>
    /// <param name="bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks">Indicates whether to look for byte order marks at the beginning of the input stream.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This constructor initializes the encoding as specified by the encoding parameter.
    /// The bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks parameter, if true, detects the encoding by looking at the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise, the user-provided encoding is used.
    /// </remarks>
    public EncodingTranslatorStream(System.IO.Stream strInput, Encoding encodingIn, bool bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Encoding encodingOut)
    {
        this.Init(strInput, encodingOut);
        this.srInput_m = new StreamReader(strInput, encodingIn, bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.  Specifies an output encoding,  and a byte order mark detection option for the input stream
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strInput">Input data, that will be decoded and re-encode into the specified output encoding</param>
    /// <param name="encodingOut">Output encoding</param>
    /// <param name="bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks">Indicates whether to look for byte order marks at the beginning of the input stream.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This constructor initializes the encoding to UTF8Encoding
    /// The detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks parameter, if true, detects the encoding by looking at the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise, the UTF8Encoding is used. See the Encoding.GetPreamble method for more information.
    /// </remarks>
    public EncodingTranslatorStream(System.IO.Stream strInput, bool bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Encoding encodingOut)
    {
        this.Init(strInput, encodingOut);
        this.srInput_m = new StreamReader(strInput, bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks);
    }

    private void Init(Stream strInput, Encoding encodingOut)
    {
        this.strInput_m = strInput;

        //Because the output bytes of an encoding translation can be larger than what we want in a single read, we need
        //somewhere to store it
        this.strOut_m = new MemoryQueueBufferStream();
        //this.strOut_m = new MemoryStream();

        this.swOutput_m = new StreamWriter(this.strOut_m, encodingOut);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return this.strInput_m.CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return this.strInput_m.CanSeek; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        this.strInput_m.Flush();
    }       

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the length of the string in bytes.  Note, depending on the encoding type of the stream, the byte length will vary,
    /// as characters may require multiple bytes for certain encodings.  Some encodings allow different byte lengths depending on the
    /// character.  This function will return the maximum amount of bytes that the string may take, as returning the actual
    /// requires processing the entire string which is time and memory consuming.
    /// </summary>
    public override long Length
    {
        get
        {
            //This returns the length of the input stream
            return this.strInput_m.Length;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The actual position in bytes (not characters)
    /// </summary>
    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return this.strInput_m.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            this.strInput_m.Position = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Our temporary pool of characters.  This acts as the middle-man when translating encodings.  Bytes are decoded into this as chars, then encoded back into
    /// bytes.  We will re-use this cache so we don't have to keep instantiating the array.
    /// </summary>
    private char[] lstChars_m;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads bytes from the stream.  Bytes will be returned in the output encoding specified, regardless of the input encoding
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer">Buffer to fill</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Start position in the buffer</param>
    /// <param name="count">Count of bytes to read and put in the buffer.  Buffer needs to be long enough to accomodate <paramref name="offset"/> + <paramref name="count"/></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (this.srInput_m.CurrentEncoding.Equals(this.swOutput_m.Encoding))
        {
            //The encodings are the same,  lets just bypass the translation stuff
            return this.strInput_m.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        //We are reading data in one encodng, and outputing the data using another encoding
        //The process is to read bytes from an input stream, decode them, based on a specified encoding, 
        //to chars which are unicode then encode them to bytes based on a specified encoding
        //Note that the number of input bytes may be more or less than the number of output bytes because
        //Some encodings are multibyte and some are not.  Even if both encodings are multibyte they still may not
        //use the same number of bytes for any given character.

        //Validate the parameters passed in
        this.ValidateBufferArgs(buffer, offset, count);

        int iTotalBytesRead = 0;

        //If there are decoded bytes still in the output stream that havent been read,  return them
        if (this.strOut_m.Length > 0)
        {
            //Read from output stream into the read buffer
            int iBytesRead = this.strOut_m.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            iTotalBytesRead += iBytesRead;

            //While there are still bytes to read from the output stream and we have reached our limit 
            while (iBytesRead > 0 && iTotalBytesRead < count)
            {
                iBytesRead = this.strOut_m.Read(buffer, offset + iTotalBytesRead, count);

                iTotalBytesRead += iBytesRead;
            }
        }

        int iRemainingBytesToRead = count - iTotalBytesRead;

        //If we still haven't reached our limit
        if (iRemainingBytesToRead > 0)
        {
            //We need to convert our input to chars, so ensure we have a buffer we can re-use, or create a new one
            if (this.lstChars_m == null || lstChars_m.Length < count)
            {
                //The max number of chars we will need to deal with is the number of bytes we want to read.
                this.lstChars_m = new char[count];
            }

            //Convert our input bytes to chars.  Reading from our input StreamReader will take care of decoding bytes, from the input stream, into chars.
            //Our streams read method accepts a byte count of bytes to return, but the StreamReader requires a char count.  Depending on the input encoding
            //specified, there may be more than 1 byte per character.  We don't know exactly how many bytes to read from the input stream, so we will
            //use the byte count as the char count.  At most this will read more bytes than we actually want, but that's ok.
            int iCharsRead = this.srInput_m.Read(this.lstChars_m, 0, iRemainingBytesToRead);

            if (iCharsRead > 0)
            {
                //Convert our chars to bytes using the specified output encoding.  Writing to our output stream writer will take care of encoding.
                //Converting chars to bytes may result in more bytes than were requested but because we're writting to an output stream that is a MemoryQueueBufferStream
                //that stream will hold on to the extra bytes, allowing us to only return what was asked for now, and let us return the rest on subsequent calls
                //to this read method.

                long lOutputPosition = this.strOut_m.Position;
                this.swOutput_m.Write(this.lstChars_m, 0, iCharsRead);
                this.swOutput_m.Flush();

                //If we need to go back the pre-write position.  
                //MemoryStream position will advance as data is written to it
                //MemoryQueueBufferStream position will not advance as data is written to it
                if (this.strOut_m.CanSeek && this.strOut_m.Position != lOutputPosition)
                {
                    this.strOut_m.Position = lOutputPosition;
                }

                //The output stream now contains a series of bytes that we can return.  When we read bytes from the stream, the data will be removed from the stream
                int iBytesRead = this.strOut_m.Read(buffer, offset + iTotalBytesRead, count);
                iTotalBytesRead += iBytesRead;
            }
        }
        return iTotalBytesRead;
    }              

    public override long Seek(long offset, System.IO.SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return this.strInput_m.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Setting the length of the stream is not supported.");
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Writing to the stream is not supported.");
    }


    private void ValidateBufferArgs(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (offset < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset", "offset must be non-negative");
        }
        if (count < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count", "count must be non-negative");
        }
        if ((buffer.Length - offset) < count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("requested count exceeds available size");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Constructors**

Because the constructor of the StreamReader [`(Stream, Encoding)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is equal to calling the overloaded constructor [`(Stream, Encoding, bool)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143457%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `true` for the bool parameter, you should use constructor chaining.

From the first link:

> The StreamReader object attempts to detect the encoding by looking at the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise, the user-provided encoding is used.

So you could simplify your code like

```
public EncodingTranslatorStream(System.IO.Stream strInput, Encoding encodingIn, Encoding encodingOut)   
     : this(strInput, encodingIn, true, encodingOut)
{}
```

---

Dead code like `//this.strOut_m = new MemoryStream();` should be removed because it only adds noise to the code instead of any value.

The same is true for comments which are saying **what** is done instead of **why** something is done. Please read this fine answer about comments: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90113/29371

---

**Possible problems**

The overridden `Position` property can cause problems if a not correctly coded subclass of stream is passed to the constructor.

Usually a `Stream` should throw a `NotSupportedException` if the `Position` property is set and the stream is not seekable. So if you check `CanSeek` before setting the `Position` you have done everything you can do to prevent any exceptions. If a subclass of the `Stream` class is passed in, which doesn't follow this pattern, noone can blame you then.

---

**Again the naming**

This block of code

> ```
> if (this.srInput_m.CurrentEncoding.Equals(this.swOutput_m.Encoding))
> {
>     //The encodings are the same,  lets just bypass the translation stuff
>     return this.strInput_m.Read(buffer, offset, count);
> }
> ```

is very hard to read/grasp at first glance. The difference between `srInput_m` and `strInput_m` is extremely small.

You should at least change `sr_Input_m` to `reader` or `streamReader` with or without your postfix of choice where as I would not use it if you always use `this.`

---

**Validation**

In the `Read()` method you have

> ```
> //Validate the parameters passed in
> this.ValidateBufferArgs(buffer, offset, count);
> ```

but you are using the parameters before the check if the encoding of the used `StreamReader` equals the encoding of the used `StreamWriter`.

Either omit the check (I guess the stream and streamreader take care of this) or move it to the top of the method.

---

**Read() method**

Basically the `Read()` method is way to long. You should consider to break it into smaller methods which are easier to maintain and also better to read.

Answer (score 1):

In the recent version of the code, if you already have read iTotalBytesRead into the "buffer" variable, the third parameter (count) in the following line:

```
iBytesRead = this.strOut_m.Read(buffer, offset + iTotalBytesRead, count);
```

must be "count - iTotalBytesRead":

```
iBytesRead = this.strOut_m.Read(buffer, offset + iTotalBytesRead, count - iTotalBytesRead);
```

otherwise it won't pass your own validation in MemoryQueuedBufferStream -- ValidateBufferArgs

Answer (score 0):

Recent revision:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class is a stream designed to perform character encoding translation from one encoding to another.
/// </summary>
public class EncodingTranslatorStream : System.IO.Stream
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Input data.  This is the data that well be decoded, and re-encoded in the specified encoding
    /// </summary>
    private System.IO.Stream strInput_m;

    /// <summary>
    /// Input stream reader.  This will be responsible for decoding the input bytes into unicode characters based on the specified input encoding
    /// </summary>
    private StreamReader rdrInput_m;

    /// <summary>
    /// Output stream reader.  This will be responsible for encoding unicode characters into bytes based on the specified output encoding
    /// </summary>
    private StreamWriter wrtOutput_m;

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds a stream of bytes, and when read, the bytes are automatically removed from the stream
    /// </summary>
    private Stream strOut_m;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.  Specifies the input and output encoding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strInput">Input data, that will be decoded and re-encode into the specified output encoding</param>
    /// <param name="encodingIn">The input character encoding to use.</param>
    /// <param name="encodingOut">Output encoding</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The character encoding is set by the encoding parameter. 
    /// The StreamReader object attempts to detect the encoding by looking at the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise, the user-provided encoding is used. 
    /// </remarks>
    public EncodingTranslatorStream(System.IO.Stream strInput, Encoding encodingIn, Encoding encodingOut)
        : this(strInput, encodingIn, true, encodingOut)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.  Specifies the input and output encoding, and a byte order mark detection option for the input stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strInput">Input data, that will be decoded and re-encode into the specified output encoding</param>
    /// <param name="encodingIn">The input character encoding to use.</param>
    /// <param name="encodingOut">Output encoding</param>
    /// <param name="bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks">Indicates whether to look for byte order marks at the beginning of the input stream.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This constructor initializes the encoding as specified by the encoding parameter.
    /// The bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks parameter, if true, detects the encoding by looking at the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise, the user-provided encoding is used.
    /// </remarks>
    public EncodingTranslatorStream(System.IO.Stream strInput, Encoding encodingIn, bool bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Encoding encodingOut)
    {
        this.Init(strInput, encodingOut);
        this.rdrInput_m = new StreamReader(strInput, encodingIn, bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.  Specifies an output encoding,  and a byte order mark detection option for the input stream
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strInput">Input data, that will be decoded and re-encode into the specified output encoding</param>
    /// <param name="encodingOut">Output encoding</param>
    /// <param name="bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks">Indicates whether to look for byte order marks at the beginning of the input stream.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This constructor initializes the encoding to UTF8Encoding
    /// The detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks parameter, if true, detects the encoding by looking at the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise, the UTF8Encoding is used. See the Encoding.GetPreamble method for more information.
    /// </remarks>
    public EncodingTranslatorStream(System.IO.Stream strInput, bool bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Encoding encodingOut)
    {
        this.Init(strInput, encodingOut);
        this.rdrInput_m = new StreamReader(strInput, bDetectInputEncodingFromByteOrderMarks);
    }

    private void Init(Stream strInput, Encoding encodingOut)
    {
        this.strInput_m = strInput;

        //Because the output bytes of an encoding translation can be larger than what we want in a single read, we need
        //somewhere to store it
        this.strOut_m = new MemoryQueueBufferStream();
        //this.strOut_m = new MemoryStream();

        this.wrtOutput_m = new StreamWriter(this.strOut_m, encodingOut);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return this.strInput_m.CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return this.strInput_m.CanSeek; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        this.strInput_m.Flush();
    }       

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the length of the string in bytes.  Note, depending on the encoding type of the stream, the byte length will vary,
    /// as characters may require multiple bytes for certain encodings.  Some encodings allow different byte lengths depending on the
    /// character.  This function will return the maximum amount of bytes that the string may take, as returning the actual
    /// requires processing the entire string which is time and memory consuming.
    /// </summary>
    public override long Length
    {
        get
        {
            //This returns the length of the input stream
            return this.strInput_m.Length;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The actual position in bytes (not characters)
    /// </summary>
    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.strInput_m.CanSeek)
            {
                return this.strInput_m.Position;
            }
            else 
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Input stream ({0}) does not support seeking.", this.strInput_m.GetType().Name));
            }
        }
        set
        {
            this.strInput_m.Position = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Our temporary pool of characters.  This acts as the middle-man when translating encodings.  Bytes are decoded into this as chars, then encoded back into
    /// bytes.  We will re-use this cache so we don't have to keep instantiating the array.
    /// </summary>
    private char[] lstChars_m;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads bytes from the stream.  Bytes will be returned in the output encoding specified, regardless of the input encoding
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer">Buffer to fill</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Start position in the buffer</param>
    /// <param name="count">Count of bytes to read and put in the buffer.  Buffer needs to be long enough to accomodate <paramref name="offset"/> + <paramref name="count"/></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        //Validate the parameters passed in
        this.ValidateBufferArgs(buffer, offset, count);

        if (this.rdrInput_m.CurrentEncoding.Equals(this.wrtOutput_m.Encoding))
        {
            //The encodings are the same,  lets just bypass the translation stuff
            return this.strInput_m.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        //We are reading data in one encodng, and outputing the data using another encoding
        //The process is to read bytes from an input stream, decode them, based on a specified encoding, 
        //to chars which are unicode then encode them to bytes based on a specified encoding
        //Note that the number of input bytes may be more or less than the number of output bytes because
        //Some encodings are multibyte and some are not.  Even if both encodings are multibyte they still may not
        //use the same number of bytes for any given character.


        int iTotalBytesRead = 0;

        //If there are decoded bytes still in the output stream that havent been read,  return them
        if (this.strOut_m.Length > 0)
        {
            //Read from output stream into the read buffer
            int iBytesRead = this.strOut_m.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            iTotalBytesRead += iBytesRead;

            //While there are still bytes to read from the output stream and we have reached our limit 
            while (iBytesRead > 0 && iTotalBytesRead < count)
            {
                iBytesRead = this.strOut_m.Read(buffer, offset + iTotalBytesRead, count);

                iTotalBytesRead += iBytesRead;
            }
        }

        int iRemainingBytesToRead = count - iTotalBytesRead;

        //If we still haven't reached our limit
        if (iRemainingBytesToRead > 0)
        {
            //We need to convert our input to chars, so ensure we have a buffer we can re-use, or create a new one
            if (this.lstChars_m == null || lstChars_m.Length < count)
            {
                //The max number of chars we will need to deal with is the number of bytes we want to read.
                this.lstChars_m = new char[count];
            }

            //Convert our input bytes to chars.  Reading from our input StreamReader will take care of decoding bytes, from the input stream, into chars.
            //Our streams read method accepts a byte count of bytes to return, but the StreamReader requires a char count.  Depending on the input encoding
            //specified, there may be more than 1 byte per character.  We don't know exactly how many bytes to read from the input stream, so we will
            //use the byte count as the char count.  At most this will read more bytes than we actually want, but that's ok.
            int iCharsRead = this.rdrInput_m.Read(this.lstChars_m, 0, iRemainingBytesToRead);

            if (iCharsRead > 0)
            {
                //Convert our chars to bytes using the specified output encoding.  Writing to our output stream writer will take care of encoding.
                //Converting chars to bytes may result in more bytes than were requested but because we're writting to an output stream that is a MemoryQueueBufferStream
                //that stream will hold on to the extra bytes, allowing us to only return what was asked for now, and let us return the rest on subsequent calls
                //to this read method.

                long lOutputPosition = this.strOut_m.Position;
                this.wrtOutput_m.Write(this.lstChars_m, 0, iCharsRead);
                this.wrtOutput_m.Flush();

                //If we need to go back the pre-write position.  
                //MemoryStream position will advance as data is written to it
                //MemoryQueueBufferStream position will not advance as data is written to it
                if (this.strOut_m.Position != lOutputPosition)
                {
                    if (this.strOut_m.CanSeek)
                    {
                        this.strOut_m.Position = lOutputPosition;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The output stream ({0}) needs to be seeked after it was written to but it does not support that operation.",this.strOut_m.GetType().FullName));
                    }
                }
                //The output stream now contains a series of bytes that we can return.  When we read bytes from the stream, the data will be removed from the stream
                int iBytesRead = this.strOut_m.Read(buffer, offset + iTotalBytesRead, count);
                iTotalBytesRead += iBytesRead;
            }
        }
        return iTotalBytesRead;
    }              

    public override long Seek(long offset, System.IO.SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return this.strInput_m.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Setting the length of the stream is not supported.");
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Writing to the stream is not supported.");
    }

    private void ValidateBufferArgs(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (offset < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset", "offset must be non-negative");
        }
        if (count < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count", "count must be non-negative");
        }
        if ((buffer.Length - offset) < count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("requested count exceeds available size");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The possible problem with the Position property is in the setter.

Comment: oh damn, that's where I meant to put it, thanks!