# Generating and storing a unique salt in Oracle database using Java

Tags: java, performance, sql, jdbc, oracle

This is my account table:

```
CREATE TABLE mwUser (
  username varchar2(20) primary key not null, 
  salt varchar2(64) unique not null,
  hashedpw varchar2(64) not null, 
  email varchar2(320) unique not null 
);
```

When I register a new user with my java webservice I automatically generate a random salt and store in the database base (see code below):

```
Connection c = dataSource.getConnection(); 
Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
boolean isFound=true;
String randomSalt="";
while(isFound){
   isFound=false;
   String randomSalt=createRandomString(); //creates salt/random string
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mvUser where salt="+randomString);
   //check if salt is unique
   while (rs.next()) {
     isFound=true;
   }
}

Statement insertStmt = c.createStatement();
String hashedPW=hash(randomSalt+pw); //generates hashed pw
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO mvUser VALUES(.....));

stmt.close();
c.close();
```

But as you can see, from my point of view my code is not clean/performant/readable because I have two statements (for checking if salt is unique and and second statement is for inserting).

How can I automatically generate an unique string(salt) and hash it at the same time. I am trying to make my code more performant and read able.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use [best practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) in general when dealing with password hashing.

- If you have to verify the database for your generated *salt* to be unique, **you're using a bad *salt generator***. Make sure to focus on using a [good generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93614/salt-generation-in-c) instead.
- Your hash function also seems weak. Consider using [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching).

---

This should not be required:

> ```
> while(isFound){
>    isFound=false;
>    String randomSalt=createRandomString(); //creates salt/random string
>    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mvUser where salt="+randomString);
>    //check if salt is unique
>    while (rs.next()) {
>      isFound=true;
>    }
> }
> ```

And for hash, I would expect something like below, where `hash` is an established hash library (PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt, ..).

```
var hashedPW = hash(iterations, randomSalt, pw);
```

Comment: but even a good salt generator doesnt ensure that the salt is unique? The likelihood that the salt already exsists is just smaller?

Comment: @Lebron11 Exactly, and in combination with a variable number of `iterations`, even if two users happen to have the same plain text password and salt, they would end up having different hashes.

Comment: And even if they don't, the chances of that happening are extremely small. So I doubt there's much risk after that. I mean, what attack is going to abuse 2 random users having the same hash if you don't know which 2 users it's about?