# Product Manager managing product listings and prices

Tags: c#, mvc, regex

For school we have to develop a product manager. The basic task is to add new products. A product has a name and a price.

*I know the one or other class is currently pretty empty but its planned to add more methods.*

The code is developed in MVC-format and comments plus texts are in German.

I would like to know what's good and what's bad (also why) and how I can improve the code in design, structure, variable/method naming, performance.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using Ferienaufgabe_2.Controller;

namespace Ferienaufgabe_2
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
           ProductList productList = new ProductList();
           productList.RenderView();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller/ProductList.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Ferienaufgabe_2.Controller
{
    class ProductList
    {
        public void RenderView()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new View.ProductList());
        }
    }
}
```

**Model/Product.cs**

```
namespace Ferienaufgabe_2.Model
{
class Product
{
    private string productname;
    private decimal price;

    public Product(string productname, decimal price)
    {
        this.Productname = productname;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    private string Productname
    {
        set
        {
            this.productname = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return this.productname;
        }
    }

    private decimal Price
    {
        set
        {
            this.price = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return this.price;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Utility/Validate.cs**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Ferienaufgabe_2.Utility
{
class Validate
{
    public bool IsValidPriceFormat(string value)
    {
        string strRegex = @"^[0-9]{1,}([\,]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}$";
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
        Match myMatch = myRegex.Match(value);
        if (myMatch.Success)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**View/ProductList.cs**

*Build with MS VS 2015 RC - form designer*

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Ferienaufgabe_2.View
{
public partial class ProductList : Form
{
    private string defaultTextAddProductTextBox;
    private string messageMissingProductname;

    public ProductList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Translations
        this.Text = "Produkteingabe";
        this.defaultTextAddProductTextBox = "Produktname";
        this.messageMissingProductname = "Bitte einen Produktnamen angeben.";
    }

    private void textBoxAddProduct_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.textBoxAddProduct.Text == this.defaultTextAddProductTextBox)
        {
            this.textBoxAddProduct.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            this.textBoxAddProduct.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void textBoxAddProduct_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.textBoxAddProduct.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            this.textBoxAddProduct.Text = this.defaultTextAddProductTextBox;
            this.textBoxAddProduct.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        }
    }

    private void textBoxAddProduct_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.AddProductToList();
        }
    }

    private void buttonAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.AddProductToList();
    }

    protected bool AddProductToList()
    {
        if (this.textBoxAddProduct.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this.messageMissingProductname);
            return false;
        }

        decimal productPrice = Prompt.ShowPriceDialog();
        this.productBindingSource.Add(new Model.Product(this.textBoxAddProduct.Text, productPrice));
        this.textBoxAddProduct.Text = this.defaultTextAddProductTextBox;
        this.textBoxAddProduct.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        this.dataGridViewProductList.Focus();
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

**View/Prompt.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Ferienaufgabe_2.Utility;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Ferienaufgabe_2.View
{
static class Prompt
{
    public static decimal ShowPriceDialog()
    {
        Validate validator = new Validate();

        // Create form and its fields
        Form prompt = new Form();
        Label textLabel = new Label();
        TextBox inputBox = new TextBox();
        Button confirmation = new Button();

        // Translations
        string defaultTextInputBox = "z.B.: 10,00";
        string messageInvalidPriceFormat = "Ungültige Preiseingabe! Z.B.: 10,00";
        string textOfLabel = "Preis";
        string textOfConfirmButton = "Prozess abschliessen";

        // Design form and its fields
        prompt.Width = 300;
        prompt.Height = 120;
        prompt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        prompt.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

        textLabel.Location = new Point(110, 15);
        textLabel.Text = textOfLabel;
        textLabel.Font = new Font("Arial", 18);

        inputBox.Location = new Point(40, (textLabel.Location.Y + textLabel.Height + 10));
        inputBox.Width = 205;
        inputBox.Text = defaultTextInputBox;
        inputBox.ForeColor = Color.Gray;

        confirmation.Location = new Point(40, (inputBox.Location.Y + inputBox.Height + 10));
        confirmation.Width = inputBox.Width;
        confirmation.Text = textOfConfirmButton;

        // Add events
        inputBox.KeyUp += (sender, e) => {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && validator.IsValidPriceFormat(inputBox.Text))
            {
                prompt.Close();
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                textLabel.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show(messageInvalidPriceFormat);
            }
        };

        confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => {
            if (validator.IsValidPriceFormat(inputBox.Text))
            {
                prompt.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                textLabel.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show(messageInvalidPriceFormat);
            }
        };

        inputBox.GotFocus += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (inputBox.Text == defaultTextInputBox)
            {
                inputBox.Text = "";
                inputBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        };
        inputBox.LostFocus += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (inputBox.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                inputBox.Text = defaultTextInputBox;
                inputBox.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        };

        // Add fields to form
        prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
        prompt.Controls.Add(inputBox);
        prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);

        // Show dialog
        prompt.ShowDialog();

        // Return converted input. This goes well anytime due to a check in the dispose actions.
        return Convert.ToDecimal(inputBox.Text);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
>    if (myMatch.Success)
>    {
>        return true;
>    }
>    return false;
> ```

That's an awful lot of code for a simple thing. Why not directly return the value?

```
return myMatch.Success;
```

"myMatch" isn't a very good name either. C# is case sensitive, so you could simply use `match`. In fact, this whole block suffers from some poor naming.

> ```
>    string strRegex = @"^[0-9]{1,}([\,]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}$";
>    Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
>    Match myMatch = myRegex.Match(value);
> ```

The latter two can be solved by taking advantage of casing, but what about `strRegex`??? Why, we just call it what it is, a (regex) *pattern*.

```
    string pattern = @"^[0-9]{1,}([\,]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}$";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None);
    Match match = regex.Match(value);
```

Whenever possible, avoid both static methods and "newing" objects inside your methods. Both make tests difficult to write.

> ```
> public static decimal ShowPriceDialog()
> {
>     Validate validator = new Validate();
>
>     // Create form and its fields
>     Form prompt = new Form();
>     Label textLabel = new Label();
>     TextBox inputBox = new TextBox();
>     Button confirmation = new Button();
> ```

Pass things as parameters, or through the ctor instead. It's called Dependency Injection, you'd do well to study it. Don't go thinking you need some special framework or anything though. Look into "Pure DI" a.k.a. "Poor man's DI".

Lastly, I think you missed the model-view-controller pattern by a bit. The controller doesn't seem to do much, while the views's code behinds are doing an awful lot of work.

Answer (score 6):

To help you get started, here's how I would write the `Product` class

```
public class Product
{    
    public Product(string productName, decimal price)
    {
        this.ProductName = productName;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }    
}
```

I used **public** to denote the visibility of the class. By default, `C#` will mark classes as `internal` which may not be obvious to other people. I specifically state the visibility to avoid any confusion.

I suggest you consider using the camel case naming convention for locals, parameters, fields e.g. product**N**ame

In this case, I used auto properties e.g.

public string ProductName **{ get; set; }**

No need to declare your own private fields (`_productname`), if you are not using them for anything. Consider using auto properties instead.

Comment: Why did you added the class attributes after the constructor? Just your personal preference or is it the way it's done in c#?

Comment: It just happened that they appeared in that order in the original code for this question. I use [`StyleCop`](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) to help me with guidance on where to place things in a class, such as public properties.

Comment: @AMartinNo1 think about it for a second, what's the very first thing you'd ever need to know about a class? You need to know how to create it, right? That's a very good reason to put your ctor first.

Comment: You can specify the setter to be private if you want to restrict how those values are set: `public string ProductName { get; private set; }`

Comment: With VS2015 and C# 6 you can define read-only properties by omitting the setter and initializing at the declaration or in a constructor. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) for more.

Answer (score 3):

In your Model you have things a little mixed up.

> ```
> private string productname;
> private decimal price;
>
> public Product(string productname, decimal price)
> {
>     this.Productname = productname;
>     this.Price = price;
> }
>
> private string Productname
> {
>     set
>     {
>         this.productname = value;
>     }
>     get
>     {
>         return this.productname;
>     }
> }
>
> private decimal Price
> {
>     set
>     {
>         this.price = value;
>     }
>     get
>     {
>         return this.price;
>     }
> }
> ```

You should have `private` properties and `public` accessors

Answer (score 3):

**Comments**

Comments should describe **why** something is done in the way it is done. Describing **what** is done does not add any value.

Comments like

> ```
> // Create form and its fields
> // Translations
> // Design form and its fields
> .....
> ```

are also a sign that this parts maybe should be extracted to separate methods.

You can find a very good read about comments here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90113/29371

**Naming**

Classes should be named using nouns or noun phrases ([naming guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx)), so a name like `Validate` is better suited for a method. You should rename the class to `Validator` or better `ProductPriceValidator` to make it more clear what the class is about.
In addition the name `Prompt` does not reflect what the class is doing. A better name would be `ProductPriceView`.

**ShowPriceDialog**

This method is in its current state clearly too long. Also, why did you make the class and all of its methods static ?

I would make the class and its methods `non static` and would add methods like

- `InitializeComponent()` for creating the view
- `ResetView()` for setting the default values of the form
- and keep the `ShowPriceDialog()` method, but I would change the returned value from `decimal` to `DialogResult` and adding a `Prize` property to get the entered prize. This needs a change in the textbox eventhandlers to call `Hide()` on the view rather than `Close()`.

---

Instead of using

> ```
> if (this.textBoxAddProduct.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
> ```

you should use [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is checking wether the passed in string is `null` or does only contain white space characters.

---

Assigning `string.Empty` makes the intention more clear than assigning `""` which by the way with older eyes not always is easy to distinguish at the first glance from `" "`.

---

Because you aren't changing these fields

> ```
> private string defaultTextAddProductTextBox;
> private string messageMissingProductname;
> ```

you should make them `readonly`.

**Validation**

IMHO the `IsValidPriceFormat()` has a decent flaw. You are assuming that the entered price will have a comma as decimal separator. If you plan to localize it to make it usable for e.g an american user, you would not only need to change the regex, but to provide a different validator so you won't break the german users.

A much better way to validate the passed price would be to use [`decimal.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns a boolean indicating if the given string could be parsed to a deciaml value. At the provided link location you can find a example of how to use this.

A useful component could also be a [`MaskedTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: About `KeyUp` event. It's requested by customer - in this case our teacher. Also if I hit enter isn't it obvious that the prompt will be closed?

Comment: I didn't noticed the `Enter`. I just thought it is weird to close the form after validation. Will update answer.

Comment: Ah ok. I just remember the reason I declared `Prompt` static. `MessageBox.Show(string);` is static as well but I see your point. And I am not sure how to retrieve a value from a non static view.

Comment: I figured out how to retrieve a value from a non static view. It's just as easy as from static class :)