# Implementing N-ary trees in C

Tags: c, tree

Looking at my code, I feel like it is not instantly clear for someone who did not write it. I feel like readability will be important for me in the future, if I'm ever to write code on an enterprise, or open source project. Do you have any advice as to how I can make this and future C more readable?

```
#include "datatypes.h"
#include <stddef.h>

//Changes the node's child (if it doesn't exist) to newChild
//or appends newChild to the end of the node's child's sibling list
void addChild ( treeNode *root, treeNode *newChild ) {
  treeNode *temp;
  if ( root->child == NULL ) {
    root->child = newChild;
  } else {
    temp = root->child;
    while ( temp->sibling != NULL ) {
      temp = temp->sibling;
    }
    temp->sibling = newChild;
  }
}

//Returns a new treeNode with default data values or {0,NULL,NULL}
treeNode newNode () {
  treeNode node = {0, NULL, NULL};
  return node;
}
```

datatypes.h

```
typedef struct treeNode {
  int n;
  struct treeNode *child;
  struct treeNode *sibling;
} treeNode;

treeNode newNode (); //Returns a treenode with default {0,NULL,NULL}
void addChild ( treeNode *t, treeNode *c ); //Adds child to the given  treeNode
```

Comment: Don't use such variable names (`t`, `j`) use descriptive names like `tree`, `root`, `node` ... and `t->child` is more readable than `(*t).child`

Comment: Leading `_` is a problem.  May conflict with future keywords: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217029/macro-naming-convention/26217870#comment41119085_26217870

Comment: I have rolled back two of your edits. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: BTW the comments are awful. They look like a mangled translation of your C code to English. Don't do that! Make your comments more high-level, e.g. your comment "Adds child to the given treeNode" is perfectly good. If someone wants to know how your code does that, he can run it in a debugger (or trace the code's execution in one's mind). Also, the comment on `newNode` is similarly long-winded, useless and error-prone - remove it or replace it with something like "Creates an empty tree". Also, the comment "and returns the root node" is incorrect (obsolete?) - remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is pretty clear for anybody with `C` background. One suggestion though - there is no need for `temp`; you may safely reuse `node`:

```
    node = node->child;
    while (node->sibling) {
        node = node->sibling;
    }
    node->sibling = child;
```

Answer (score 4):

Comment, Comment, Comment. If you want any other person on this blue planet to know whats going on in your code in the easiest way possible, comment your code.

```
// This is what the code does in the next line.
/* I'm going to write a block of text to tell you the purpose of what this function
is trying to accomplish */
```

Your code doesn't have to be pretty or legible for that matter, but a few comments go along way.

Also, whitespace for your `if` and `while` statements are appealing to the eye and allow the reader to break apart your conditional statements. Trying to cram as much as you can on one line causes headaches when trying to interpret them.

Comment: I disagree. Comments are often more a code smell than a helpfull hint. Also, they tend to get wrong over time. Try to refactor the code so that your intent becomes clear (good variable names, good function names, easy-to-read-coding style, short functions, etc.).

Comment: @PeterSchneider - But having no comments at all in the code above is okay for open source? I agree with the other statements you've said but not one comment about the function or anything is fine?

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Real coders do not comment, huh? Sorry, but this is... well... just wrong. Code only tells you "how". Comments should of course not duplicate that, they should tell you "what" (one level up). And then the documentation should tell you the "why". You can write the clearest code in the world, that does not make comments unnecessary. At the very least, they can provide an indication for the poor sod debugging your code where your "how" didn't actually do "what" you intended...

Comment: I've been working on two commercial products with a10 years plus history. Sometimes it's a funny game to trace a comment back in time if it made sense back then and when they become missleading. I know this isn't optimal but people tend to ignore documentation and dive directly into the code fixing the current problem and do not update the comment. Maybe I had bad luck, maybe its typical. Don't get me wrong good comments are great - but bad ones are worse than none. And I comment my code if it is necessary BTW ;) (math stuff,  why this nasty workaround and not the obvious way, etc.)

Comment: Okay, I can say I've never worked in industry but still understand the importance of a comment in code. If the comment itself is misleading then you are also working with those that do not value a comment either and will only update the product and not the documentation. I wouldn't take a company seriously if their documentation wasn't accurate or as important as the code they write.

Comment: @KillaBytes: "the product" is the final binary with all of it's new features and bugfixes compared to the last version. Comments are internal documentation and "the company" doesn't get money for it. Managers are pushing for code - not for comments ;) As a professional you can (and should!) try to improve the internal code quality. But management will almost never ask for this and it will only work in small steps and it is a long march.

Comment: @PeterSchneider - It sounds like you will only do something if your manager asks it of you or it makes money for the final product since it is tedious to say the least. You find no value for the comments in code?

Comment: @KillaBytes: officially, I only do what my manager is asking for. Inofficially I try to improve the code base with every commit (this rarely means comments for me but sometimes they are an improvement). The trick is to find a way between. You do not get paid for 8 hours maintenance a day. If you do zero, your code base is rotten in 2 years.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I've got 15+ years in the industry, most of the time doing maintenance on C++ code written by people who thought they were so good at coding they didn't need to comment their code. Hint: They weren't.

Comment: @DevSolar: only have 5 years in industry doing mostly maintenance in C/C++/C#. Some predecessors thought they were smart some where. But I have seen mostly misleading comments and tend to ignore them all together. As I said above, I may had bad luck but even kernel code only have a sparse documentation and uses few comments (open source - not management / marketing driven development)

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I generally don't take what Linus et al. have produced or said so far as a good example for *anything*, but I think we're getting off-topic here. ;)

Comment: @KillaBytes: The angle you should take with management re. code comments is the time saved in maintenance. You only need to write them *once*, but they will significantly speed up anybody later being introduced to, or tasked to debug, the code. Write once, read many. Of course you need to update comments if the code they refer to undergoes significant refactoring, but the time you saved by *understanding* the code faster when that time came surely makes up for that. Unless, of course, you are in the business of fire-and-forget coding a.k.a. "let the customer cope with this once I'm done".

Comment: @DevSolar and PeterSchneider - Thank you for your responses, coming from having no real industry experience it's nice to hear from those with experience on the subject.

Comment: @DevSolar: Here an epic answer on proper use of comments: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90113/42409

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Would you concurr with http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90113/42409 on what makes good comments?

Comment: @Deduplicator: That answer is 50% agreeing with me. I partially disagree with the other 50%. But don't you think *this* answer has enough comments already?

Comment: @DevSolar: No, but we are getting there ;-)

Comment: @Deduplicator: I agree: I try to express my ideas with pure code. If I fail with that, I must place a comment. In a perfect world I would even agree with the JavaDoc-part - at least for public methods/ functions (or the counterpart in other languages). I could skip the code and just read the docs. But if it is not company policy, devs tend to ignore them when they modify your code and they become misleading.  But DevSolar is right - if we want to talk more, we should use chat or similar ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily simplify your `addChild`-method:

```
void addChild ( treeNode *root, treeNode *newChild ) {
    treeNode** p = &root->child;
    while(*p)
        p = &p[0]->sibling;
    *p = newChild;
}
```

And there's no reason for `newNode` to exist as it's trivial (C99 being available for compound-literals):

```
treeNode newNode () {
    return (treeNode){0}; // C needs at least one initializer
}
```