# Animal inheritance hierarchy

Tags: java, object-oriented

I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing superclasses right.  Also, I welcome critique on Java structure/syntax etc.

Animal.java:

```
public class Animal{
    private static int counter = 0; // how many animals we have created (to demonstrate a static variable)
    private Boolean isWild = true; // is the animal wild?
    private Boolean hasSharpPointyTeeth = false; // does it have sharp, pointy teeth?!
    private int age = 0; // how old

    Animal(){ // default constructor
        this.isWild = isWild;
        this.hasSharpPointyTeeth = hasSharpPointyTeeth;
        this.age = age;

        counter++;
    }

    Animal(Boolean isWild, Boolean hasSharpPointyTeeth, int age){
        this.isWild = isWild;
        this.hasSharpPointyTeeth = hasSharpPointyTeeth;
        this.age = age;

        counter++;
    }

    //begin getters/setters
    public void setIsWild(Boolean isWild){
        this.isWild = isWild;
    }
    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }
    public void setHasSharpPointyTeeth(Boolean hasSharpPointyTeeth){
        this.hasSharpPointyTeeth = hasSharpPointyTeeth;
    }
    public Boolean getIsWild(){
        return isWild;
    }
    public Boolean getHasSharpPointyTeeth(){
        return hasSharpPointyTeeth;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
    public static int getCounter(){
        return counter;
    }
    //end getters/setters

    public String speak(){
        return "Grrrr!";
    }

    public String toString(){
        String out =    speak() + "\n" + 
                        "Age: " + getAge() + "\n" +
                        "Wild? " + getIsWild() + "\n" + 
                        "Has Sharp Pointy Teeth? " + getHasSharpPointyTeeth() + "\n";
        return out;
    }
}
```

Dog.java

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
    private String name = "None";
    private String owner = "None";
    private String breed = "Unknown";
    private String sex = "Unknown";

    Dog(){
        super(false, false, 0); // call the constructor from the Animal class
        this.name = name;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    Dog(Boolean isWild, Boolean hasSharpPointyTeeth, int age, String name, String owner, String breed, String sex){
        super(isWild, hasSharpPointyTeeth, age); // call the constructor from the Animal class
        this.name = name;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    //begin getters/setters
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setOwner(String owner){
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public void setBreed(String breed){
        this.breed = breed;
    }
    public void setSex(String sex){
        this.sex = sex;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }
    public String getBreed(){
        return breed;
    }
    public String getSex(){
        return sex;
    }
    //end getters/setters

    @Override
    public String speak(){
        return "Woof!";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String out =    super.toString() + // call the toString method of Animal, not the overridden one in Dog
                        "Name: " + getName() + "\n" +
                        "Breed: " + getBreed() + "\n" +
                        "Sex: " + getSex()+ "\n" +
                        "Owner: " + getOwner() + "\n";
        return out;
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Dog fluffy = new Dog(false,true,3,"Fluffy","Ted","Westie","Male");
        Animal rabbit = new Animal(true,true,8);

        System.out.println("We made " + Animal.getCounter() + " animals.  Here's their info:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(fluffy);
        System.out.println(rabbit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private Boolean isWild = true; // is the animal wild?
private Boolean hasSharpPointyTeeth = false; // does it have sharp, pointy teeth?!
```

Why are you using the wrapper class? Use the primitive `boolean` instead.

Also, about comments:

```
private static int counter = 0; // how many animals we have created (to demonstrate a static variable)
private Boolean isWild = true; // is the animal wild?
private Boolean hasSharpPointyTeeth = false; // does it have sharp, pointy teeth?!
private int age = 0; // how old
```

All the comments here are unnecessary with better variable names. Comments [explain why, not what](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90113/49308).

All of the variable names are fine, maybe except `counter`: could be `numberOfAnimals`...

### NAMING

```
public Boolean getIsWild()
```

should be `isWild()`. Likewise,

```
public Boolean getHasSharpPointyTeeth()
```

should be `hasSharpPointyTeeth()`.

But `getAge()`, for example, should stay `getAge()`.

```
public static int getCounter()
```

should be `getNumberOfAnimals()`

`speak()` is poorly named. I would've expected it to print what it says, but it just returns what it says. I would either change it to do what I said, even though I would suggest against it, or rename it. I would suggest rename it to `getSpeech()`.

### Misc

```
    this.isWild = isWild;
    this.hasSharpPointyTeeth = hasSharpPointyTeeth;
    this.age = age;
```

In the default constructor is completely unnecessary: it already has those values, does it need those same values again? Same in the `Dog` class:

```
    this.name = name;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.sex = sex;
```

The begin and end getters/setters comments are unnecessary: why are those there?

The `(){` after each method should be `() {` according to Java standard conventions.

Constructors should be `public`.

I think the `sex` property should be `Animal`'s.

Also you should check the parameters and see if they are valid: you don't want age to be set to `-1` or `breed` to be set to something like `hello`... do you? I'll leave that up to you, but the general format is this:

```
if (is not valid) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Why is it not valid?);
}
```

You shouldn't be testing with `main()`. Instead use JUnit 4 or any similar testing library.

### Final Code

```
public class Animal {
    
    private static int numberOfAnimals = 0;
    private boolean isWild = true;
    private boolean hasSharpPointyTeeth = false;
    private int age = 0;
    private String sex = "Unknown";

    public Animal() {
        numberOfAnimals++;
    }

    public Animal(String sex, boolean isWild, boolean hasSharpPointyTeeth, int age) {
        this.sex = sex;
        this.isWild = isWild;
        this.hasSharpPointyTeeth = hasSharpPointyTeeth;
        this.age = age;
        numberOfAnimals++;
    }

    public void setIsWild(Boolean isWild) {
        this.isWild = isWild;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setHasSharpPointyTeeth(Boolean hasSharpPointyTeeth) {
        this.hasSharpPointyTeeth = hasSharpPointyTeeth;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public Boolean isWild() {
        return isWild;
    }

    public Boolean hasSharpPointyTeeth() {
        return hasSharpPointyTeeth;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfAnimals() {
        return numberOfAnimals;
    }

    public String getSpeech() {
        return "Grrrr!";
    }

    public String toString() {
        String out = getSpeech() + "\n" + "Age: " + getAge() + "\n" + "Wild? "
                + isWild() + "\n" + "Has Sharp Pointy Teeth? "
                + hasSharpPointyTeeth() + "\n";
        return out;
    }
    
}
```

---

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

    private String name = "None";
    private String owner = "None";
    private String breed = "Unknown";

    public Dog() {
        super("Unknown", false, false, 0);
    }

    public Dog(boolean isWild, boolean hasSharpPointyTeeth, int age, String name,
            String owner, String breed, String sex) {
        super(sex, isWild, hasSharpPointyTeeth, age);
        this.name = name;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpeech() {
        return "Woof!";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String out = super.toString()
                + "Name: " + getName() + "\n" + "Breed: " + getBreed() + "\n"
                + "Sex: " + getSex() + "\n" + "Owner: " + getOwner() + "\n";
        return out;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @h3rrmiller Please try not to accept answers instantly; wait a couple of hours or days for the best answer.

Comment: I'm pretty active on the unix site so I'll see other answers trickle in and accept them if they're better. But thanks for the tip

Comment: Just FYI, you didn't add sex into the constructor of your revised Animal class. Nice review though

Comment: @RicHo Thanks for the catch, didn't notice it.

Comment: @MannyMeng my really hurts to see such a long list of parameters in `Dog` constructor and it smells too. Must be a code smell, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2244912/867461) thread. Ideally it should be some `struct` but in Java we can pass some `enum`, wdyt?

Comment: @vivekpoddar I know it's bad, but I was too lazy to complain about that :) you may add an additional answer explaining that.

Comment: @MannyMeng sure! I just need to think some proper name :)