# Word Counter Project

Tags: beginner, c, parsing, io

I recently read *K&R The C Programming Language* and wanted to write a small program to count the occurrence of each word in the input (std-input - I piped a file with all shakespeare pieces in there).

Since I wanted to learn how to split source files into multiple files with this project I pretty much outsources every function I could think of. 
This is the part I'm most unsure, whether its bad practice or not (I include multiple libraries from the std-lib multiple times. Is this a bad thing?). You'll see.

**find_words.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "word_finder.h"
#include "binary_tree.h"

#define MAX_WORD 20

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char word[MAX_WORD];
    struct tnode *root = NULL;
    int min_count = 1500;
    int max_count = 20000;

    if (argc > 3) {
        printf("Usage: ./find_words [min_count] [max_count] <INPUT_PIPE\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(argv[1] != NULL)
        min_count = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(argv[2] != NULL)
        max_count = atoi(argv[2]);

    while(get_word(word, MAX_WORD) != 0)
        if(isalpha(word[0]))
            root = addtree(root, word);

    treeprint(root, min_count, max_count);

    return 1;
}
```

**word_finder.h**

```
int get_word(char *word, int limit);
```

**word_finder.c**

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "io.h"

int get_word(char *word, int size)
{
    int c;
    while((isspace(c = getch())))
        ;

    if (c == EOF)
        return 0;

    int i = 0;
    do 
    {
        *(word+i++) = c;
    } while (isalpha(c = getch()) && i < size-1);

    *(word+i) = '\0';
    ungetch(c);

    return i;
}
```

**io.h**

```
int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);
```

**io.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "io.h"

#define BUFSIZE 100

/* Buffer can hold up to BUFSIZE - 1 characters */
char buf[BUFSIZE];
int bufhead = 0;
int buftail = 0;

int getch(void)
{
    if (bufhead == buftail)
        return getchar(); 
    else {
        int temp = buf[buftail];
        buftail = (buftail + 1) % BUFSIZE;
        return temp;    
    }
}

void ungetch(int c)
{
    if ((bufhead + 1) % BUFSIZE == buftail % BUFSIZE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Buffer full, dropped %c.\n", c);
    } else {
        buf[bufhead] = c;
        bufhead = (bufhead + 1) % BUFSIZE;
    }
}
```

**binary_tree.h**

```
struct tnode {
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct tnode *right;
    struct tnode *left;
};

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *, char *);
void treeprint(struct tnode *, int, int);
```

**binary_tree.c**

```
#include "binary_tree.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *strduplicate(const char *);
static struct tnode *talloc(void);

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *node, char *word)
{
    int cond;

    if(node == NULL) {  //The word doesnt exist in the tree
        node = talloc();
        node->word = strduplicate(word);
        node->count = 1;
        node->left = node->right = NULL;
    } else if((cond = strcmp(word, node->word)) == 0) {
        node->count++;
    } else if(cond < 0) {
        node->left = addtree(node->left, word);
    } else {
        node->right = addtree(node->right, word);
    }

    return node;
}

static struct tnode *talloc(void)
{
    return (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
}

static char *strduplicate(const char *s)
{
    char *p;

    p = (char *) malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    if(p != NULL)
        strcpy(p,s);

    return p;
}

void treeprint(struct tnode *node, int min_count, int max_count)
{
    if(node != NULL) {
        treeprint(node->left, min_count, max_count);
        if(node->count >= min_count && node->count <= max_count)
            printf("%4d %s\n", node->count, node->word);
        treeprint(node->right, min_count, max_count);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for the long post (I'm not 100% sure if this is allowed - I'll delete the post immediately if it's not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "whether its bad practice or not" to sub-divide.  No, not bad practice - in fact good in certain areas.  It often comes down to maintenance - how many functions per file and the optimal answer is highly problem dependent.  IMO, too often files need fewer functions than code needs fewer files.
2. `ungetch()` have troubles as it ungets a `EOF`.  This special value should not be unget-able.  Further – I have doubts that when `char` is `signed`, that these 2 functions properly handle some char values as the real `getc()` returns `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  Example: If `(char) 255` is un-gotten, on get, it may have the value of `EOF`.   Recommend making your unget buffer `unsigned char`.
3. Unclear to the whole need for user `unget/get` functionality as standard library ones well handle 1 level of `get/unget`.
4. The whole `addtree()`, should input be alphabetical, devolves into a linked list.  Consider [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) trees.
5. Below test `i` against `size` *after* the assignment.  Recommend test *before* to cope with pathological `size` values like 1.  Recommend re-write - avoiding code like `(word+i++)`.  Further, consider `size_t` rather than `int` for array indexes.

   ```
   // from
   do {
     *(word+i++) = c;
   } while (isalpha(c = getch()) && i < size-1);

   // to
   if (size > 0) size--; 
   while (i < size) {
     word[i++] = c;
     c = getch()
     if (!isalpha(c)) {
       break;
     }
   }
   ```
6. `MAX_WORD` is fuzzy.  Suggest `MAX_WORD_SIZE`.
7. `ungetch()` and `getch()` look way too much like standard functions.  Suggest `io_ungetch()` and `io_getch()`.
8. Cast not needed.

   ```
   // return (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
   return malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));

   // p = (char *) malloc(strlen(s)+1);
   p = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
   ```
9. Magic number 4.  Why 4?

   ```
   // printf("%4d %s\n", node->count, node->word);
   printf("%d %s\n", node->count, node->word);
   ```
10. If a function does not modify a pointer's contents, use `const`.

    ```
    // void treeprint(struct tnode *node, int min_count, int max_count)
    void treeprint(const struct tnode *node, int min_count, int max_count)
    ```
11. Minor: .h file `void ungetch(int);` --> `void ungetch(int ch);`  Also add a little documentation of the .h files, it goes a long way in understanding.
12. Minor: spelling: `doesnt` --> `doesn't`
13. Pedantic point: `char` may be signed and `is...()` defined for `unsigned char` and `EOF`, not `signed char`.

    ```
    // if(isalpha(word[0]))
    if(isalpha((unsigned char) word[0]))
    ```

Comment: Good and comprehensive one. A few points: #8: A good link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc #9: That's a format-string, and the exact choice of format is quite arbitrary. #11: Yep, that's one of the places including the name is good documentation: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90111/guessing-a-number-but-comments-concerning.