# One program using three functions to compare two double-precision numbers

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, floating-point

I am currently learning C++ though Bjarne Stroustrup book *Programming Principles and Practices using C++*.

Going through the drills, I am trying to purposefully write efficient and readable code (good coding practices. However, I think I may be overdoing it with my use of functions for tasks within my program.

```
//Function to check if the entered numbers are similar in value
double similarValues(double valueBigger, double valueSmaller)
{
    if ((valueBigger - valueSmaller) < 0.01) {
        return 1;   //Return 1 if the values are similar
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

//Function checks which value is larger
double valueLarger(double value01, double value02)
{
    if (value01 > value02) {
        return value01;
    }
    else if (value01 < value02) {
        return value02;
    }
    else {
        return 0;       //Return 0 if the values are equal!
    }
}

//Function checks which value is smaller
double valueSmaller(double value01, double value02)
{
    if (value01 > value02) {
        return value02;
    }
    else if (value01 < value02) {
        return value01;
    }
    else {
        return 0;       //Return 0 if the values are equal!
    }
}

int main()
{

    // Reads two integers on each loop and prints them//
    double value02; 
    double value01;

    while (cin >> value01 >> value02) {

        // Checks if the functions valueSmaller & valueLarger have not retuned 0
        if (valueSmaller(value01, value02) != 0 || valueLarger(value01, value02) != 0) {
            cout << "The smaller value is: " << valueSmaller(value01, value02) << " , the larger value is: " << valueLarger(value01, value02) << "\n";

            //Checks if the values are at least similar, returns 1 if true
            if (similarValues(valueLarger(value01, value02), valueSmaller(value01, value02)) == 1) {
                cout<<"The numbers are almost equal. \n";
            }
        }
        // If functions valueSmaller & valueLarger have returned 0 then do the below instuction
        else if (value01 == value02) {
            cout << "Both of these numbers are equal!" << "\n";
        }
        // If the values entered cannot be processed then output an error message
        else {
            cout << "Not a value I know! Incorrect input" << "\n";
        }

    }
}
```

Please critically (I do not mind if it is harsh) state what programming practices I am not following or following correctly. Also, whether my coding is on par with what you would deem as following great coding conventions.

- Am I overdoing the functions?
- Am I using return values differently then they should be used?
- Is my code readable?
- Are my comments accurate and to the point or are they vague?

Comment: you can use `std::max` and `std::min` to get larger and smaller values

Comment: I think you are doing fine. Small function of less than a dozen lines are perfect. Rule of Thumb: a function should not be larger than a terminal window so you can read the whole thing without scrolling (rule of thumb two: Don't make your font smaller so it will fit :-). Though you could do with practice naming the functions (and finding their equivalent in the standard). If you test for equality first then your other function become easier to write.

Comment: @LokiAstari Another rule of thumb I use: if you have to rewrite the same block of code three times, make it a method... Although, perhaps that one doesn't apply to this particular program. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your functions and their use are very curious:

- A function to determine if two values are similar should be symmetric in its arguments, and return a `bool`.
- A function determining the truth of a property should be called `is@`. `similarValue` is a bit of a puzzler, which is actually good as the functions behavior is very surprising.
- A conditional expression returns a `bool`, which can be implicitly converted to an integer of value 0 (`false`) or 1 (`true`).
- I'm not sure what I should do with `valueSmaller` and `valueLarger`, but I am sure that I don't want to see anything like them ever again.

Other points:

- Seems you also don't know the conditional-operator (`expr ? value-if-true : value-if-false`). It can be used to write things better, but beware of getting carried away with it.
- You are using `using namespace std;`.
  That's a bad idea, read "[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)".
- When you output string- and char-literals consecutively, just concatenate them together. Also, if you have a length-1-string-literal, a char-literal can serve the same purpose more efficiently.
- Your comments are, I'm sorry to say, useless, as they just rephrase some of the more obvious code.
  When you use descriptive names, most other comments for describing what code does also become superfluous (exception: doc-comments which will be extracted for bare-bones documentation).
  Comments are for giving non-obvious reasons for doing things you do, reasons for doing them the way you do them, or describing how you do something.
  See [this good answer by rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90113/42409) about how to properly comment.

Comment: `using namespace std` is perfectly fine. It's bad if used on header files.

Comment: @Pr0kram3r: Did you read the post I linked? I concede that in a header-file it's a more obviously unconscionable evil, but being more subtle in implementation-files doesn't make it right.

Comment: In a header file using "using" is a mistake. In a .cpp file I think you are on your own. If you don't have any name clashes I don't see any serious problem with a "using" clause.

Comment: @Pr0kram3r `using` isn't the issue here. `using namespace @` is. `using std::string` is fine.

Comment: In fact, not even `using namespace @` is a problem. The problem is with `using` such a huge and containing so many common words as identifiers (string, vector, pair, tuple, ends) namespace as `std` — even if not all the headers introducing these are included, they are allowed by the Standard to be included by each other.

Comment: converting length-1-string-literals to chars should be doable for the compiler. I wouldn't change that as it ruins readability. Using `std::endl` may just be a better proposition

Comment: @WorldSEnder: The compiler *might* be able to do it, *in theory*. There's no advantage to relying on the compiler doing it though, a 1-size-string and a char-literal are equally readable and need the same amount of source-code. But *why* would I want to separate out `'\n'` and then follow it with a manual flush? That just puts paid to performance *and* readability.

Comment: @Deduplicator  Thanks for your pointers! However, I was unsure about what you meant by your second dot-point. Is similarValue a good name for the function or not?

Comment: @user36278: No, it isn't. `isSimilar` or the like would be better. The bigger problem with it is its contract though...

Answer (score 12):

I'm just going to break this down by the method.

---

```
double similarValues(double valueBigger, double valueSmaller)
{
    if ((valueBigger - valueSmaller) < 0.01) {
        return 1;   //Return 1 if the values are similar
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Since we're only interested on the truth value result here, we should use a `boolean` return to decide if the numbers are "similar". This could also be much more flexible and terse. We can use `std::abs` to achieve this.

```
//returns true if the variance is less than 0.01
bool valuesAreSimilar(double a, double b) {
  return abs(a - b) < 0.01;
}
```

---

```
//Function checks which value is larger
double max(double value01, double value02)
{
    if (value01 > value02) {
        return value01;
    }
    else if (value01 < value02) {
        return value02;
    }
    else {
        return 0;       //Return 0 if the values are equal!
    }
}

//Function checks which value is smaller
double min(double value01, double value02)
{
    if (value01 > value02) {
        return value02;
    }
    else if (value01 < value02) {
        return value01;
    }
    else {
        return 0;       //Return 0 if the values are equal!
    }
}
```

Right up front, something to think about is that considering the case where the values are equal is probably unnecessary. Keep in mind you can always check if the values are equal outside of the context of these methods (and in nearly every case, this is preferable)(Thank you to Deduplicator for reminding me to address this). These are perhaps good to write for practice, but in a real code base, I recommend using `std::min` and `std::max` (credit to @MORTAL). For good recommendations in optimizing these two, check out @Greg Burghardt's answer. I'm changing the signatures to `max()` and `min()` for brevity's sake.

---

```
int main()
{
    double value02; 
    double value01;

    while (cin >> value01 >> value02) {
        if (valueSmaller(value01, value02) != 0 || valueLarger(value01, value02) != 0) {
            cout << "The smaller value is: " << valueSmaller(value01, value02) << " , the larger value is: " << valueLarger(value01, value02) << "\n";
            if (similarValues(valueLarger(value01, value02), valueSmaller(value01, value02)) == 1) {
                cout<<"The numbers are almost equal. \n";
            }
        }
        else if (value01 == value02) {
            cout << "Both of these numbers are equal!" << "\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Not a value I know! Incorrect input" << "\n";
        }

    }
}
```

This one is a little wonky to look at. We can do a bit with it to make it nice by checking if the values are equal first. Another thing to note is that your final `else` statement can't be reached. If you'd like to do error checking, I recommend doing a stream failure check.

**Update**: As Ruslan pointed out, the `while` loop will never be entered if there is an assignment failure, so we'll move the failure message outside the loop.

```
int main()
{
    double value02; 
    double value01;

    while (cin >> value01 >> value02) {
        if (value01 != value02) {
            cout << "The smaller value is: " << min(value01, value02) 
                << " , the larger value is: " << max(value01, value02) << "\n";
            if (valuesAreSimilar(value01, value02)) {
                cout << "The numbers are almost equal. \n";
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Both of these numbers are equal!" << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "Not a value I know! Incorrect input" << "\n";
}
```

---

Your final code could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::min;
using std::max;

//returns true if the variance is less than 0.01
bool valuesAreSimilar(double a, double b) {
  return std::abs(a - b) < 0.01;
}

int main()
{
    double value02; 
    double value01;

    while (cin >> value01 >> value02) {
        if (value01 != value02) {
            cout << "The smaller value is: " << min(value01, value02) 
                << " , the larger value is: " << max(value01, value02) << "\n";
            if (valuesAreSimilar(value01, value02)) {
                cout << "The numbers are almost equal. \n";
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Both of these numbers are equal!" << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "Not a value I know! Incorrect input" << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @Ruslan `cin.fail()` should return true if the assignment fails due to a character/string being typed. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it should fail, but first the `operator>>()` will return object convertible to `false`, and you won't enter the body of `while`.

Comment: @Ruslan I see, so there is no checking to do. I will correct this.

Comment: Have you tried to compile your final code, BTW? It doesn't compile because you've not `#include`d `<cmath>`.

Comment: @Ruslan Which compiler are you using?

Comment: g++ 5.1. See [this sample](http://ideone.com/2Xosbm).

Answer (score 6):

- Function `similarValues()` should be a `bool` instead of a `double` and return `true` or `false`
- You could probably combine your other two functions into one that returns different things for larger the same or smaller instead of returning the larger type or again use a bool to determine whether a value is larger and return `true` or `false`.
- Consider using switch statements instead of if statements for more readable code.

  ```
  cout << "The smaller value is: " << valueSmaller(value01, value02) << " ,     the larger value is: " << valueLarger(value01, value02) << "\n";
  ```
- Instead of using `<< "\n"` consider using `<< endl`
- Other than that your code is reasonably readable, try and keep your comments concise and to the point and make sure you only use doubles when you need to.
- You are probably not overdoing functions although some of them could be combined as I have already said.
- Consider using `using std::cout` instead of `using namespace std` or avoid it all together.

Comment: Not using `std::endl` is one of the points OP did right. You don't want to flush your performance down the drain without good reason. Though for the few cases he outputs a length-1-string, he should prefer outputting a single `char`.

Answer (score 6):

This started out as a comment since I'm only going to discuss `similarValues()`, but it grew a bit big, so here we go.

First of all, I strongly recommend @nukeforum's suggestion that you use the `abs()` function. Also, as has been mentioned aplenty already, `similarValues()` should return a bool:

```
bool similarValues(double a, double b) {
    return abs(a - b) < 0.01;
}
```

Now, about that `0.01`... you're using `0.01` as the epsilon value here. It's kind of a magic number, but more importantly, that's a HUGE epsilon value. Machine epsilon for a `double` type is about `1e-16`. The amount of precision you need will vary, but when I did competitive programming I liked using `const double EPS = 1e-9;`.

It might be nice to be able to specify a precision when you're performing the equality check. To that end, it might be nice to have something like:

```
const double EPS = 1e-9;
bool similarValues(double a, double b, double eps = EPS) {
    return abs(a - b) < eps;
}
```

Comment: I intended to address the magic number problem in my answer, but apparently I forgot to in the sea of everything else. Fantastic answer. +1

Comment: [Never mind.  Looks like you've covered it]

Answer (score 4):

- Echoing others, your `similarValues` function should be returning a boolean. Calling it `areSimilarValues` reads better and is more descriptive.
- The two arguments are called `smallerValue` and `biggerValue`, yet you don't actually know that one is bigger than the other. It's equally as plausible you could call the function like this: `similarValues(55, 0.1)` in which case the variable names are completely wrong from their actual values. I would recommend something more generic in this case: `a` and `b` or `value1` and `value2`.
- The `similarValues` function can be reduced to one line:

  ```
  #include <cmath>

  bool function areSimilarValues(double a, double b) {
      return abs(a - b) < 0.01;
  }
  ```

  Also note that no comments are required when you give things descriptive names, and use appropriate return types.
- Like others have said, the `valueLarger` and `valueSmaller` functions could use better names, such as `getLargerValue` and `getSmallerValue`.
- The `valueLarger` and `valueSmaller` functions return zero when the values are equal? The other `return` statements return one of the numbers. Returning zero feels like a logic error. If they are equal, just return one of them. It doesn't really matter which one you return since they are equal.

  ```
  double getLargerValue(double a, double b) {
      if (a > b) {
          return a;
      }
      else if (b > a) {
          return b;
      }
      else {
          // Values are equal
          return a;
      }
  }
  ```

  Even this could be reduced to:

  ```
  double getLargerValue(double a, double b) {
      return b > a ? b : a;
  }
  ```

  If `b` is greater than `a`, return `b`. Otherwise, `a` is either larger than `b` or `a` and `b` are equal, so return `a`. And just for good measure, the `getSmallerValue` function:

  ```
  double getSmallerValue(double a, double b) {
      return b < a ? b : a;
  }
  ```
- Now that I think about it, Mathematics has a term for getting the larger or smaller value of two numbers: Maximum and Minimum. These would be good names for `valueLarger` and `valueSmaller`:

  ```
  double maximum(double a, double b) {
  }

  double minimum(double a, double b) {
  }
  ```

Comment: ad 3: The reduction is wrong if passing the not-smaller value first is no longer part of the contract. ad4: `valueLarger` and `valueSmaller` are more complicated and confusing beasts, as you later say. Your redefinition in point 5 should be quite reasonable. But there are standard-functions or that different concept...

Comment: @Deduplicator: What do you mean by "The reduction is wrong if passing the not-smaller value first is no longer part of the contract." for bullet point #3. The logic between the OP's code and my version appear to be the same.

Comment: Yes. But in OPs code, that function's precondition was that first >= second (stated through the arguments names), while in your replacement that's no longer the case.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Which function in the OP's code are you talking about. I think I'm looking at a different function than you are in reference to our comments.

Comment: If my edited comment needs more clarifiaction, add a new comment...

Comment: @GregBurghardt I think Deduplicator is trying to say that in your third bullet point, you don't account for `a` being smaller than `b`. In which case, the variance could still be `.01`, but the return would not register true because the value would be `-.01`. To fix this, just use `abs()` in the `cmath` lib.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Speaking of `cmath`, the `cmath` lib also has `fmax()` and `fmin()`. No need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: @nukeforum: I see what you mean. I'll update my answer when I get a chance. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer to incorporate @nukeforum's suggestion to call the `abs` function on the result of `a - b`.

Comment: If I saw the functions valueLarger and valueSmaller in actual code, I would rename them to "weirdMaximum" and "weirdMinimum" to indicate they return something related to the minimum or maximum, but behave weird in some way.