# Basic JavaScript template engine using replace, match and RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

To practice with regular expressions, I wrote this basic template engine in JavaScript in addition to a simple test case to make sure it works correctly.

I am wondering if there is any improvements I can do or if I am correctly following JavaScript coding style and conventions. Thanks in advance.

In short,

1. {{= expression}} --> evaluates expression (context is optional)
2. {{0}}            --> evaluates based on given array index
3. {{name}}         --> evaluates based on given json values

Template code (does not require any dependency):

```
(function() {
    this.amirTemplateEngine = function() {
        var self = this;
        var _tokensToReplace, _values, _array;

        // evaluate in-line expressions
        self.evaluateString = function(string, options) {
            _tokensToReplace = string.match(new RegExp(/({{=[^}]*}})/g)) || [];

            _tokensToReplace.map(function(token) {
                string = string.replace(token, (function() {
                    return eval(token.replace("{{=", "").replace("}}", ""));
                }).call(options && options.context ? options.context : self));
            });

            return string;
        };

        // replace given object
        self.replaceGivenObject = function(string, options) {
            _values = options && options.values ? options.values : {};
            _tokensToReplace = string.match(new RegExp(/({{[ ]*[^}.]+[ ]*}})/g)) || [];

            _tokensToReplace.map(function(token) {
                string = string.replace(token, _values[token.replace(" ", "").replace("{{", "").replace("}}", "")]);
            });

            return string;
        };

        // replace given array index
        self.replaceGivenArray = function(string, options) {
            _array = options && options.array ? options.array : {};
            _tokensToReplace = string.match(new RegExp(/({{[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*}})/g)) || [];

            _tokensToReplace.map(function(token) {
                string = string.replace(token, _array[parseInt(token.replace(" ", "").replace("{{", "").replace("}}", ""))]);
            });

            return string;
        };

        // helper function
        self.format = function(string, options) {
            // evaluate expressions
            string = self.evaluateString(string, options);

            // if options.array is defined, then evaluate template
            string = self.replaceGivenArray(string, options);

            // if options.values is defined, then evaluate template
            string = self.replaceGivenObject(string, options);

            return string;
        };

        // for chainability
        return self;
    };
})();
```

Testing the code (making sure output is correct):

```
var template = require('./amir-template-engine');

(function() {
    var self = this;
    something = "something else!";
    var template = "\
                    <h2 class='{{= (true).toString()}}'>{{0}} {{1}} {{2}}</h2>\
                    <p>{{= 4 > 0 ? 'good' : 'bad'}}</p>\
                    <p>{{= something }}</p>\
                    <p>{{name}}</p>\
                ";

    var result = "\
                    <h2 class='true'>seyed amir hossein</h2>\
                    <p>good</p>\
                    <p>something else!</p>\
                    <p>amir</p>\
                ";

    var templateObj = new amirTemplateEngine();

    testResult = templateObj.format(template, {
        array: ["seyed", "amir", "hossein"],
        values: {
            name: "amir"
        },
        context: self
    }) == result;

    console.log("Test is" + (testResult ? "" : " NOT") + " passing!");
})();
```

[Link to GitHub repository](https://github.com/amir734jj/basic-javascript-template-engine)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use this to make an even simple template engine just for what I needed. Also, helped me understand how i could get the matches from a regex and perform the replacement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## RegEx

#### `[ ]*` vs `\s*`

`[ ]*` which is same as `*`(space followed by a star) matches zero or more occurrences of space. This is not flexible as it only allows users to use spaces. If user use tabs, this regex will fail. Use `\s*`, which matches all the space characters.

Quoting from http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

> `\s` stands for "whitespace character". Again, which characters this actually includes, depends on the regex flavor. In all flavors discussed in this tutorial, it includes `[ \t\r\n\f]`. That is: `\s` matches a space, a tab, a line break, or a form feed. Most flavors also include the vertical tab

#### RegExp Constructor vs RegEx Literal

`new RegExp()` is used to create a new regex. This form of regex accepts a string as the first argument and returns new regex. This is used when creating regex from a variable. Since this uses string, the backslash is used to escape following character. This will produce unexpected results when regex itself contains a backslash. Example, `new RegExp('\s')` will return `/s/`. When using a backslash in this form, they need to be escaped `new RegExp('\\s')`. This is not necessarily difficult but requires to take care of escaping.

Passing regex literal syntax to the constructor is same as literal syntax to create regex. So, `new RegExp(/({{=[^}]*}})/g)` is same as `/({{=[^}]*}})/g`.

#### Mistake

The regex for object `/{{\s*([^}.]*)\s*}}/g` doesn't work for all cases. `[^{.]*` means to match anything which is not `{` AND `.`. If the key of object contains `.`, this regex will fail. Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/aWS9NM/2). Removing `.` solves this problem.

Not a mistake, but a validation. Using `+` quantifier instead of `*`. `*` says, match zero or more of the previous pattern. For example, `{{=[^}]*}}` will match `{{=}}` which you might not want to match and process.

#### Better use of capturing groups

The regex `/({{=[^}]*}})/g` will match the string starting with `{{=` to the `}}` literal and put the complete string in first captured group. Then inside `replace`, `{{=` and `}}` are again replaced

```
token.replace("{{=", "").replace("}}", "")
```

This can be improved by removing those characters from capture group.

```
/{{=([^}]*)}}/g
```

This regex will match only string contained in `{{=` and `}}`. Thus, removing the need of those two replace statements. The same thing can be used for the other two regexes.

With above improvements, the regex will be as below:

1. `/{{=([^}]+)}}/g`
2. `/{{\s*([^}]+)\s*}}/g`
3. `/{{\s*(\d+)\s*}}/g`

If the expressions do not contain spaces in between them, `[^}]+` can be replaced by `\S+`(one or more non-space characters).

## JavaScript

#### `match` => `map` => n * `replace`

In the three functions, you're first using `match` to get the matches then iterating over it and using `replace` inside it. This is not at all necessary. Simple `replace` is sufficient in this case.

Rewritten `evaluateString`

```
// Note: I've removed `call()` here
return string.replace(/{{=([^}]*)}}/g, function(m, $1) {
    return eval($1);
});
```

`$1` is the actual expression inside delimiters here. Similarly, other two methods can be written.

#### Other small improvements:

1. Naming: `something`, `string`.
2. Using `_` prefix when variables are not local/private to the method: `_tokensToReplace`, `_values`, `_array`
3. Missing strict mode: [What does “use strict” do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/2025923)
4. Really need those comments? [Guessing a number, but comments concerning](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/90111/79668)
5. Use `===` to compare variables. [Which equals operator (`==` vs `===`) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/2025923)
6. For default values, `||` can be used instead of ternary.
7. The default value for `_array` should be `[]` instead of `{}`.

**Demo:**

```js
(function() {
  this.amirTemplateEngine = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.evaluateString = function(string, options) {
      return string.replace(/{{=([^}]*)}}/g, function(m, $1) {
        return eval($1);
      });
    };

    self.replaceGivenObject = function(string, options) {
      var _values = options && options.values || {};

      return string.replace(/{{\s*([^}]*)\s*}}/g, function(m, $1) {
        return _values[$1.trim()];
      });
    };

    self.replaceGivenArray = function(string, options) {
      var _array = options && options.array || [];

      return string.replace(/{{\s*(\d+)\s*}}/g, function(m, $1) {
        return _array[$1];
      });
    };

    self.format = function(string, options) {
      string = self.evaluateString(string, options);
      string = self.replaceGivenArray(string, options);
      string = self.replaceGivenObject(string, options);

      return string;
    };

    return self;
  };
})();

(function() {
  var self = this;
  something = "something else!";
  var template = "\
                    <h2 class='{{= (true).toString()}}'>{{0}} {{1}} {{2}}</h2>\
                    <p>{{= 4 > 0 ? 'good' : 'bad'}}</p>\
                    <p>{{= something }}</p>\
                    <p>{{name}}</p>\
                ";

  var result = "\
                    <h2 class='true'>seyed amir hossein</h2>\
                    <p>good</p>\
                    <p>something else!</p>\
                    <p>amir</p>\
                ";

  var templateObj = new amirTemplateEngine();

  testResult = templateObj.format(template, {
    array: ["seyed", "amir", "hossein"],
    values: {
      name: "amir"
    },
    context: self
  }) == result;

  console.log("Test is" + (testResult ? "" : " NOT") + " passing!");
})();
```

**My Take** I'd use [constructor pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript) with overridden `toString` method and single regex for replacement.

```js
function MyTemplate(str, config) {
  this.str = str;
  this.config = config;
}
MyTemplate.prototype.toString = function() {
  var object = this.config && this.config.values || {};
  var array = this.config && this.config.array || [];

  return this.str
    .replace(/{{(=?.*?)}}/g, function(m, $1) {
      $1 = $1.trim();

      return $1.startsWith('=') ? eval($1.substr(1)) :
        /^\d+$/.test($1) ? array[$1] : object[$1];
    });
};

(function() {
  var self = this;
  something = "something else!";
  var template = `<h2 class='{{= (true).toString()}}'>{{0}} {{1}} {{2}}</h2>
                    <p>{{= 4 > 0 ? 'good' : 'bad'}}</p>
                    <p>{{= something }}</p>
                    <p>{{name}}</p>`;

  var result = `<h2 class='true'>seyed amir hossein</h2>
                    <p>good</p>
                    <p>something else!</p>
                    <p>amir</p>`;

  var templateObj = new MyTemplate(template, {
    array: ["seyed", "amir", "hossein"],
    values: {
      name: "amir"
    },
    context: self
  });

  var testResult = templateObj.toString() === result;
  console.log("Test is" + (testResult ? "" : " NOT") + " passing!");
})();
```